# Prevent change of selection in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, selection

I have a ListView. I want to prevent changing selection.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" MinHeight="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Partners}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPartner, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
             <Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding partnerId}"/>             
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and I have in ViewModel:

```
public Partner SelectedPartner
{
    get { return _selectedPartner; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedPartner == null) //when it isn't selected I select to new value
        {
            _selectedPartner = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPartner");
        }
        else // when it is selected I don't change value and I want to do not change highlighting in view
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPartner");
        }
    }
}
```

it is called corrrectly but highlighting of new/old selection is still changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution is set property `IsEnabled` to `false` after user select item from `ListView`.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" MinHeight="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Partners}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPartner, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedPartner}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <ListView.View>
       ...
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```